# How to use Limit and Offset properly

Tags: mysql

I am using the query:

```
select *
from time
where date = '2018-03-10'
limit 0,5;
```

[Here is image of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CndqN.png)

Which I expect to return output from the 1st row, but it skips the first row of data and show result from 2nd row.

I also try

select * 
from time 
where date='2018-03-10' 
order by date 
limit 5 offset 0;

Everytime i call it offset increased by 5 but the result skip the data ...it donot show me data where name =sss and www...but show the remaining data why???

Comment: Please show the table's schema (**not** as an image) and tell us which column(s) define row order.

Comment: Sorry guys for disturbing you ...as this Code works perfect...i have some error in my code

Comment: if you have another question, ask it as a new question. If my answer answered your question, please "accept" it (click the tick mark on the answer's left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have no `order by` clause, the definition of what is the "first" row is arbitrary.

To return rows predictably when using `limit`, you must define the row order by specifying an `order by` clause, eg:

```
select *
from time
where date = '2018-03-10'
order by id -- specify whatever column(s) define the order
limit 0,5
```